# Error message when creating a postgresql container using Podman

Tags: postgresql, repository, podman, podman-compose

I am unable to create a postgress container using Podman in Ubuntu from why Windows terminal and I don't know why.

this is my command :

```bash
podman pod create --name postgress-container -p 8080:8080
```

this is the message I get:

"**Error: repository name must have at least one component**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably missing the image name `postgres:<version>`
Also podman pod is not the right command to create a container. Pods provide Infrastructure for containers. Read more here: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/01/15/podman-managing-containers-pods

In your case i would run something like this:

```bash
podman create -it --name postgress-container -p 8080:8080 postgres:15.1
```

but if you start this container it won't run, because you need to set initial postgres password, like so:

```bash
podman create -it --name postgress-container -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -p 8080:8080 postgres:15.1
```

or better formatted:

```bash
podman create -it --name postgress-container \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
-p 8080:8080 \
postgres:15.1
```

See also docs from postgesql on dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Most docker commands can be made to docker commands by replacing docker with podman.